# Select com senha MD5 retornando vazio

Tags: php, mysql, md5

Estou usando a consulta abaixo para realizar o login,ele estava funcionando normal com senhas normais,mais agora estou migrando para a senha Md5,só que esta dando somente senha invalida,creio que seja a o meu select que esta com erro `"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usu_login = '".$login."' and usu_senha = 'MD5(".$senha.")'";` mais não estou conseguindo enxergar,o que poderia ser ?

```
include("conn_user.php");


$login= $_POST["login"];
$senha =$_POST["senha"];
```

$usuarios = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usu_login = '".$login."' and usu_senha = '".MD5($senha)."'";
       $result_usuarios = mysql_query($usuarios,$conn_user);
         $u = mysql_fetch_object($result_usuarios); 
          if(mysql_num_rows($result_usuarios) == 1 ){

```
$v_nome          = $u->usu_nome;
$v_senha         = $u->usu_senha;

echo"$v_nome";
echo"$v_senha";


}
```

No banco esta a senha cadastrada assim:

> 2171d30f75d516c10c2f

Já na consulta o que esta passando esta maior:

> 2171d30f75d516c10c2f4c79dd270542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sua query esta errada , faça assim

```
$usuarios = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usu_login = '".$login."' and usu_senha = '".MD5($senha)."'";
```

Comment: Ainda esta dando erro,mais estranho foi que,como editei la na pergunta,no select a senha ta maior que no banco. no banco esta assim: 2171d30f75d516c10c2f mais na consulta ta assim: 2171d30f75d516c10c2f4c79dd270542  o que poderia ser.

Comment: qual as configuração do seu campo que armazena a senha? é varchar quanto ? Posta o erro que ta dando na minha query,

Comment: era isso,vlw,o campo senha esta com varchar(20)  assim não granvando todo o md5.

Comment: rssss q bom q ajudei

Comment: Obrigado novamente.